# In MS Word how do I add a hotkey for lists?

Tags: microsoft-word, text-editors, text-formatting

How do I change the hotkey for the list button in MS Word?

It's this button in the menu bar:

[image]

I know there is a place where you can change all the hotkeys, I just can't seem to find this one.

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>T</kbd> to open the *Word Options* dialog box (or click *File* in the upper left corner and then click *Options*).

[image: Customize Ribbon]

In the left part select *Customize Ribbon*, then click the *Customize...* button (at the bottom of the dialog box).

[image]

Then in *Categories:* box select the category that contains the command or other item that you want to change the keyboard shortcut and in the *Commands:* box select it.

Look at *Current keys* (or *Currently assigned to*) to see already assigned shortcut(s), select the shortcut witch you want to change, in the *Press new shortcut key:* field press the new combination and then click *Assign* button at the left bottom.

Answer (score 1):

It's called FormatBulletDefault.

```
File > Options > Customize Ribbon > Keyboard shortcuts: Customize…
```

[image]